# Meteor mail sending getting error

Tags: meteor

When we send mail in meteor it gives the error.Please help me.

```
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://abc@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/";

            // Send the e-mail
                Email.send({
                    to: "abc@gmail.com",
                    from: "sbc@gmail.com",
                    subject: "Website Contact Form - Message From ",
                    text: "Hello"
                });
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
 Exception while invoking method 'userRegistration' AuthError: Invalid login - 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsng
I20150615-14:31:12.494(5.5)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/vamsi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ullkdf++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:76:1)
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:153:1)
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at [object Object].userRegistration (app/server/registration.js:24:23)
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150615-14:31:12.495(5.5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MAIL_URL` login and password should be URI encoded using `encodeURIComponent` :

```
var login = encodeURIComponent("abc@gmail.com");
var password = encodeURIComponent("password");
var domain = "smtp.gmail.com";
var port = 465;

process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://" + login + ":" + password + "@" + domain + ":" + port;
```

It will give you something like `smtp://abc%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465`.

Comment: I am getting this error now::  Exception while invoking method 'userRegistration' AuthError: Invalid login - 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsGm
I20150615-15:29:46.498(5.5)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/vamsi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1ullkdf++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
I20150615-15:29:46.498(5.5)?     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.j @saimeunt

Comment: encodeURIComponent for this one any packge needed? @saimeunt